# Get distinct record from table using zend functions?

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, distinct

I am getting all records like this in Zend:

```
$table = new Model_Student_Object();
$select = $table->select();
echo $select->assemble();die();
```

Result of above code is following query:

```
SELECT `student`.* FROM `student`
```

Now I want to get distinct records by Zip code. So query should be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `student`.zip FROM `student` WHERE `student`.zip != ''
```

How will I right above query with zend functions ??

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    $db = Zend_Db::factory( ...options... );
    $select = new Zend_Db_Select($db);
$select= $db->select()->distinct()->from('s'=>'student'),'zip')->where('practiceID in("1") and s.zip!='')
```