# Get unique values of a SQL column

Tags: php, sql, unique

Say I have a table with some columns as

-conversation_id,

-col2,

-user_id.

I want to grab all the rows corresponding to user_id. There could be, say, 20 rows returned for a particular, but there are only say 3 unique conversation_id values.

What is the fastest way to get these values, rather than going through each one and figuring out the unique ones?

I must say, I mean this in PHP!

Thankss!!

Comment: Please clarify your question. Table structure, sample data and sample output would help.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT conversation_id 
          FROM conversations 
          WHERE user_id='2'";
```

Comment: I think this might work. Quick question, how would this work with Zend? Could something like this work? $this->fetchAll($this->select()->where('user_id =?',$user_id)->distinct('conversation_id')); ?

Comment: I never worked with zend.. sorry but I can't help you with this.. You should try it and see if it works or not..

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT conversation_id, user_id
      FROM conversations
      GROUP BY user_id, conversation_id
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
select distinct conservation_id,user_id
from table 
group by user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT conversation_id FROM conversations WHERE user_id = userID
```

[Get distinct record from table using zend functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6110284/get-distinct-record-from-table-using-zend-functions)

Answer (score 0):

The DISTINCT keyword is used to select only unique items from the result set.

for ex in case zend:

> $db->select()->distinct('u.conversation_id')->from(array('u'=>'user'))->where('u.user_id = ?',$user_id);